# How to implement SUM operation in Google OR-Tools for C#

Tags: c#, or-tools

I would like to know how can I implement a **SUM** operation in C# using OR-Tools. In my problem, I have the following constraint:

[Constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFN5B.png)

**NOTE:** My problem is a Linear Programming Problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arithmetic operators:

```
model.Add(4 * r + 2 * p == 56);
```

or

```
model.Add(LinearExpr.Sum(new IntVar[] {r, p}) == 20);
```

See: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/sat/doc/integer_arithmetic.md